# Local array not being refreshed when bash function is called

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash function in which I set a variable `lon` and an array `pwr`.
But I have noticed that the array is not being refreshed everytime I
run the function.

```
local lon=0 pwr=()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshed"? It would be best to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem -- not your entire script, just enough to show what you're talking about.

Comment: At the start the array should be emptied if it is local variable, but either I have to empty it myself at the beginning or I might be using a globally scoped array in some other called function.

Comment: A little bit more code would be useful. With just a variable name there's not much to reproduce. And if understand correctly what you mean by "the array is not being refreshed ..." - maybe put it inside the function?

Comment: It works as I expect when I test it. Without an example showing the problem you're seeing, I doubt anyone can help.